# How do I assign two doubles to different variables depending on their value?

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to compare the value of two double inputs and assign them as different variables depending on which one is greater. I have this code so far but it doesn't seem to be working. What should I change?

```
double a, b;
double q, w;

cout << "Enter the first value of the first range: " << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "Enter the second value of the first range: " << endl;
cin >> b;


if (a < b) {
    a = q, b = w;
}
else {
    b = q, a = w;
}
```

Comment: `q` and `w` are never initialized.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Did you mean to assign to `q` and `w` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant to do is:

```cpp
if (a < b)
{
    q = a;
    w = b;
}
else
{
    q = b;
    w = a;
}
```

By the way, a more compact way to achieve the same result would be:

```cpp
q = std::min(a, b);
w = std::max(a, b);
```

Comment: `std::tie(q, w) = std::minmax(a, b);` for a one-liner.

Comment: Or even `auto [q, w] = std::minmax(a, b):` to initialize the variables when they're declared.